# Powershell, Stop-Job takes too long

Tags: multithreading, powershell, timeout, jobs

I created a powershell job, I want to limit it's running time to 10 seconds.
so I used the Wait-Job command, and if it times out I execute a Stop-Job command.
The problem is that the Stop-Job command takes about 2 minutes.
How can I fix it and stop the job immediately?

```
While($hasTimeFromNTP -eq $false)
{
    Write-Host "Start get time from NTP" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    Start-Job -Name GetNTPTime -ScriptBlock $getTimeFromNtp | Out-Null
    $result = Wait-Job GetNTPTime -Timeout 10
    if($result -ne $null)
    {
        $NTPTime = Receive-Job GetNTPTime
        $hasTimeFromNTP = $true
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "GetTimeFromNTP timed out"
        Stop-Job GetNTPTime
        Remove-Job GetNTPTime -Force
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I experienced this slow stop-job on one machine but not others.  And after rebooting that machine, I no longer encounter it there either.

Comment: Make sure the code doesn't hang on any lines in the job, because it will stop faster if the code is actually running and not waiting (like a network receive). Also, use "Start-Sleep" instead of "[Threading.Thread]::Sleep()". Because Start-Sleep can be interrupted, but the win API Sleep cannot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see a `-Force` parameter on Stop-Job.  One option would be to have the Job return the PowerShell process id it is running in `$pid` as the initial output.  You could use that pid to Stop-Process on the Powershell.exe spun up for that background job.  That's harsh but if you don't want to wait for 2 minutes, I'm not seeing other ways to force the job to stop quicker.

Comment: Very nice suggestion, but... First caveat: the job doesn't return the pid, but its child does. I sucessfully kill the child process, but... Second caveat: the "main" job continues running. When I try to stop it, I takes the same ridiculous amount of time to stop. I'm going to try the new "Start-ThreadJob" cmdlet. I'll post here if I get any success. Thanks for the suggestion!